# Using Python parser to sniff delimiter Spammed to STDOUT

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

When using `pandas.read_csv` setting `sep = None` for automatic delimiter detection, the message `Using Python parser to sniff delimiter` is printed to `STDOUT`. My code calls this function often so this greatly annoys me, how can I prevent this from happening short of going into the source and deleting the print statement.

This is with pandas 0.13.1, Python 2.7.5

Comment: pass ``engine='python'`` as well (that message shouldn't be printed in any event)

Comment: @Jeff this totally works, will accept if you put into answer form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 'bug' in that I think this is a debugging message.

To work-around, pass `engine='python'` to disable the message.